# Cocos2d close scene

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone, scene

I have a problem with my application cocos2d. I do not know how to close a scene. I get this error: You can't run an scene if another Scene is running. Use replaceScene or pushScene instead'

Help me please

Bye bye

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume, that you are trying to change current scene with

```
[[CCDirector sharedDirector] runWithScene: newScene];
```

Use

```
[[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene: newScene];
```

or

```
[[CCDirector sharedDirector] pushScene: newScene];
```

instead.

`replaceScene` will remove previous scene, `pushScene` allows you to pop pushed scene later to return to your first scene in the state it was before pushing new scene.

Anyway, in the future you should post the code where you get errors to allow somewho here to be able to understand your problem better.

Comment: blank black page means that you don't have any content on your new scene

Comment: Thank's for your answer. I try your solution but it doesn't charge cocos2d view. A blank page appears. This is my code:
CCScene *scene = [HelloWorldLayer sceneWithCalendar:1 rootViewController:self];

Comment: it loads the rootviewcontroller but not cocos2d view

Comment: When you use cocos2d, you should not use viewController instance except cases when you need to add some UIKit elements, like modal views, etc. Simply create your scene, add content to it(only CCNode subclasses, not UIKit objects, and use replaceScene/pushScene)

Comment: I need viewcontroller to add items. Do you know where is the problem?
If you need I can post more code.

Comment: what items do you need to add? in most case it is enough to use application's rootViewController, that you can get from application delegate.

Comment: I followed this tutorial: http://www.raywenderlich.com/4817/how-to-integrate-cocos2d-and-uikit for integrate cocos2d view in my rootviewcontroller.

Comment: you still not answer what UIKit elements do you want to add

Comment: The buttons I need are in the RootViewController.xib
To start the scene, from the RootViewController.m in viewDidLoad, I have 
[[CCDirector sharedDirector] setOpenGLView: GLView];
CCScene * scene = [HelloWorldLayer sceneWithCalendar: 1 rootViewController: self];
    
Is it wrong to charge my scene like this? Do you know an other way to do it?
Thank you for your answers